# Windows going over the edge of the screen

Tags: xorg, arch-linux, xorg.conf, fluxbox

I'm running Arch Linux on my laptop with Fluxbox as my WM. Many times I open a window and part of it will go off the edge of the top of the screen making it impossible for me to see the top of it. How can I configure my screen's boundaries?

Comment: See http://fluxbox-wiki.org/index.php/Keyboard_shortcuts, you can edit  `~/.fluxbox/keys` and add a key that does `:MoveTo * 0 Lower` if there's nothing already defined.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't appear to work.

Comment: grab it and move it into the visible area?

Comment: The top pane of the window (the part I would "grab") is off the screen so I cannot move it.

Comment: In Openbox, I can ALT+leftclick/drag any window to move it (no titlebar needed, click any part of the window). Does Fluxbox do this, too?